# Increase performance of multiple PNG composition

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, air

I'm in the need of creating an image composed of multiple PNGs with transparency. My solution works perfectly in desktop, but I'd like to know if I could increase performance  on mobile (iOS).

My current solution is as follows:

First I load all the images to memory with `ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_LOAD` as to avoid any CPU and lag while loading and decoding images.

Second I load the needed images to a `Sprite` which is never added to the display list.

Finally I compose all the images into a `BitmapData` object, and fade the new composed image over the previous one.

```
bitmapData.draw(compositionBufferSprite,null,null,null,rect,false);
```

I need to compose the whole image (instead of having all the PNGs on the stage without any composition) because I need to make the transition from the previous image to the new one as seamless as possible.

I tried working directly with the pixel data of the images and such, but the performance and time spent on working was exactly the same as using `draw()`. I also tried using `drawWithQuality()` with `StageQuality.LOW` and there was no difference at all. My conclusion at the time was that Air has already optimised all that bitmap work and it really doesn't matter if I `draw()` or compose directly from `BitmapData`.

I've thought about creating an ANE (native extension) but I have no clue if that would allow greater performance. So far it seems ANEs are only there for accessing native APIs not share work load.

Do you have any ideas on how I could improve this?

Comment: Well for instance, one of the benefits if you compose the image outside the display list is that there are many transparent pixel calculations that only happen once instead of every frame. This also has an impact in performance when fading images in and out, specially in mobile. I'm not sure Stage3D would provide any benefits in calculating the composited image, but if you can provide some proof about that in an answer I will try it for sure.

Comment: `cacheAsBitmap` doesn't help when you have changing content such as this case. When doing fades it will recalculate the cached bitmap on every frame. http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/08/cacheasbitmapop.html

Comment: As for using Stage3D, if you really think that would help in the calculations please provide some kind of proof in an answer (which is the purpose of this site).

Comment: If you really think you are up to the technical challenge please take some time to express your ideas through an answer, instead of sharing another irrelevant link. That would be a lot more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the performance difference may be negligible at this point, you should try a process called **blitting**.

Essentially you consolidate all different frames of your PNG's into a single (bitmap) sprite sheet and then shift the bitmap data around to change frames by calling `bitmapData.scroll(x, y)`

The [author of this blog](http://www.photonstorm.com/as3/is-pixel-blitting-in-as3-really-worth-the-effort) was able to achieve a significant increase  in performance and decrease in memory consumption over regular movieclips.

[Here is a link to the greensock library which describes the process in further detail.](http://www.greensock.com/blitmask/)

Comment: I think I already tried that without knowing it was called blitting. I tried to `bitmapData.copyPixels()` from each PNG to the the final composited image and there were no performance improvements over `bitmapData.draw()`. I will try again and post my code, maybe I did something wrong.